# Using typealias to hold a template for an array

Tags: swift

I really just joined this community to get help with one particular question, specifically, on how to declare a type that holds a variety of information types in a specific order. For context, I have the code example that I'm using below.

`typealias Template = [String, Array<Any>, String, String]`

This in turn will be used both to store data and to filter through it in further functions as follows...

```
var HamburgerToppings: [String] = []
var Salads: [String] = []
let Example: [Template] = [ABC, HamburgerToppings, XY, ZZ]
let Example2: [Template] = [DEF, Salads, GH, IJ]
var ExampleList: [Template] = [Example, Example2]
func DoTheThing() {
    for Template in ExampleList {
            if Template[0] == DEF {
                    print("SALADS!")
            } else {
                    print("BURGERS!)
            }
      }
}
```

If anyone could figure out what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a completely different declaration that needs to be made, I would be very grateful for the advice.

Many thanks,
-P. OAK

Answer (score 2):

A fixed-length collection of values is a tuple, not an array. What you meant was this (note parentheses, not brackets).

```
typealias Template = (String, Array<Any>, String, String)
```

That said, I think what you meant was this:

```
typealias Template = (String, [String], String, String)

let hamburgerToppings: [String] = []
let salads: [String] = []
let example: Template = ("ABC", hamburgerToppings, "XY", "ZZ")
let example2: Template = ("DEF", salads, "GH", "IJ")
let exampleList: [Template] = [example, example2]

func doTheThing() {
    for template in exampleList {
        if template.0 == "DEF" {
            print("SALADS!")
        } else {
            print("BURGERS!")
        }
    }
}
```

You should not use a tuple here, though, at all. This should be a struct, like this:

```
struct Template {
    let identifier: String
    let toppings: [String]
    let something2: String
    let something3: String
}

let hamburgerToppings: [String] = []
let salads: [String] = []
let example = Template(identifier: "ABC", toppings: hamburgerToppings, something2: "XY", something3: "ZZ")
let example2 = Template(identifier: "DEF", toppings: salads, something2: "GH", something3: "IJ")
let exampleList: [Template] = [example, example2]

func doTheThing() {
    for template in exampleList {
        if template.identifier == "DEF" {
            print("SALADS!")
        } else {
            print("BURGERS!")
        }
    }
}
```

Tuples tend to be fairly inflexible. They can be useful for quick, one-time anonymous types (particularly as return values), but by the time you're putting a typealias on them, you almost certainly meant to use a struct.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple instead:

```
typealias Template = (String, Array<Any>, String, String)
...
let Example: Template = (ABC, HamburgerToppings, XY, ZZ)
...
func DoTheThing() {
    for Template in ExampleList {
            if Template.0 == DEF {
                    print("SALADS!")
            } else {
                    print("BURGERS!)
            }
      }
}
```

> Tuples
>
> Tuples group multiple values into a single compound value. The values
>   within a tuple can be of any type and do not have to be of the same
>   type as each other.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#Tuples